Allow clipboard access using selenium with python
I am trying to copy and paste content on an online webpage using python selenium.
While pasting the contents, I am facing clipboard read access permission pop ups.
Pop-up Image
Can this be handled by setting any Chrome options to allow clipboard access?
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")


do you need to copy the content? can't you just scrape it?

I am trying to copy and paste the element. The error is faced while pasting content from the clipboard

what is the "element"? and where are you trying to paste it?

The idea was to copy content within Microsoft Office Excel from one cell to another

Just use native code to read clipboard.

It's kinda dummy answer, but, have you try disabled the notifications of the Browser?
option.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

This is related to this Q/A. Python - turn off notifications with selenium
In case this didn't work, you should try this answer as well

I was actually able to solve this by adding experimental option as:
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.clipboard": 1})

Tried disabling the notifications but it didn't work since I wanted to allow the clipboard access.
